# Get Post's Excerpt Without the Wrapping <p> tags and the Read More link

Tags: theme-development, tags, excerpt

I want to get the post's excerpt TEXT ONLY.

Currently, I'm using `get_the_excerpt()`, but it returns a string in the following format:

```
<p>LOREM IPSUM!&hellip; <a href="http://localhost/post/3" class="read-more">Read More</a></p>
```

I need to get the `LOREM IPSUM` (real excerpt text) only, without the wrapping `<p>` tags or the `<a>` link inside.

Is there any way to get this string, using WordPress and PHP functions?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `strip_all_tags()`? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_strip_all_tags

Comment: @WebElaine I did, the result string is: `LOREM IPSUM!&hellip; Read More`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
$string ='<p>LOREM IPSUM!&hellip; <a href="http://localhost/post/3" class="read-more">Read More</a></p>';
$string = preg_replace('/<a[^>]*(.*?)<\/a>/s', '', $string);
echo wp_strip_all_tags($string);
```

> //return LOREM IPSUM!…